# Election voting recursive function - Stanford CS106B issue

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

I'm experiencing some issues understanding/executing this problem. Basically, this is self-directed, and would appreciate if someone could shed light **on the structure of the recursion (pseudocode of some kind would be appreciated).**

What I'm stuck on is Problem 3 - search for "Every Vote Counts."

http://see.stanford.edu/materials/icspacs106b/H18-Assign3RecPS.pdf

My attempt at understanding it is you can generate the number of voting outcomes without the block specified at the index. If the block pushes the number over the majority of votes, then it is critical. But how do I translate this idea into code?

**Clarification**
This is the warm-up problem that they are referring to, which works, that needs to be altered to answer the above problem:

```
bool CanMakeSum(Vector<int> & nums, int targetSum) {

if (targetSum == 0) { 

    counter++;
    cout << listSubset(partial_solution) << endl;

} else {

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {

        int element = nums[i];

        Vector<int> rest = nums;
        rest.removeAt(i);
        partial_solution.add(element);

        int newTargetSum = targetSum - element;

            if (CanMakeSum(rest, newTargetSum)) {

                return true;

            }

        int remove_place = partial_solution.size() - 1;
        partial_solution.removeAt(remove_place);

    }
}


if (counter > 0) {

    cout << "The number of subsets that exist are: " << counter << endl;
    return true;

}

return false;
}

string listSubset(Vector<int> &partial_solution) {

string solution = "These total up to the sum: ";

for (int i = 0; i < partial_solution.size(); i++) {
    solution += IntegerToString(partial_solution[i]) + " ";
}

return solution;

}
```

Comment: The task mentions that 'If you skipped the warm-up, now might be a good time to reconsider that decision…', so - did you skip the warm-up? ;-)

Comment: Please put the problem statement in the question itself, not just a link to it.

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question, and give more detail, and give example code? Making _less_ effort the second time round isn't likely to improve responses. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23633999/creating-a-vote-counting-recursive-function-around-an-election-narrative since deleted)

Comment: Looking at the warmup exercises, they basically tell you how to solve this problem!

Comment: I did go through the warmup exercises but something just doesn't compute! My warmup exercises compile and work properly, but I'm just not making the jump to complete this problem. Don't have access to the code here, but will post it. Any ideas at all will really help!

Comment: The warm-up mentions a function `ListSubsets`.  Sounds like you just need to manipulate this function a bit to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some set of voting blocks,

```
std::vector<int> v = { 4, 2, 7, 4 }
```

There's a total of 17 votes, with a majority of `floor((17 + 1) / 2)` or 9 votes needed to swing the election.

Lets assume the collection is indexed from zero (it will be in a vector after all), and you want to find the critical votes for block 3 (which has 4 votes).

First, build a collection of the remaining blocks:

```
std::vector<int> r = { 4, 2, 7 }
```

Now find the *[powerset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset)* of that collection. The exercise makes reference to a 'ListSubsets' function you presumably worked on before; it will be relevant. Reimplementation is easy using `std::set` and a bit of recursion. If you wanted to do this using `std::vector` exclusively, you'll have to do uniqueness testing yourself.

```
void find_powerset(std::set<std::set<int>> &powerset, std::set<int> initial)
{
  powerset.insert(initial);

  for (auto i = initial.begin(); i != initial.end(); i++)
  {
    std::set<int> new_set(initial);
    new_set.erase(new_set.find(*i));
    find_powerset(powerset, new_set);
  }
}
```

You can invoke this simply enough,

```
std::set<std::set<int>> powerset;
find_powerset(powerset, std::set<int>(r.begin(), r.end()));
```

Which will ultimately generate stuff like this (though `std::set` will not keep things in this order, of course).

```
{ }
{ 4 }
{ 2 }
{ 7 }
{ 4, 2 }
{ 4, 7 }
{ 2, 7 }
{ 4, 2, 7 }
```

Now simply add up the total votes in each subset:

```
0, 4, 2, 7, 6, 11, 9, 13
```

How many of these voting outcomes which don't already exceed the majority count, will exceed the majority count when combined with the current block's votes? You may find the "warmup B" task in the exercise to be relevant.

This step can be combined with the previous one, by modifying the `powerset` function above to only return subsets whose sum falls into the appropriate range. This is left as an exercise to the reader.

Anyway, the answer is "just 2", `{ 7 }` and `{ 4, 2 }`. In all other outcomes, the vote of the final block won't change anything. Easy!

Comment: I do understand the logic behind this answer -- it's just the actual implementation of the recursion I'm not seeing. Any tips?

Comment: So you understand the logic, and you've done the warmup exercises, and you're still stuck?

Comment: Yep, I know it sounds ridiculous, but I'll post my answers to the warmup exercise in an hour or so as an edit to the original question. I'd be really grateful if you could have a look and maybe make a suggestion?

Comment: @marchon I've added a small chunk of code. If that's not enough, there may be no hope for you!

Comment: Thanks for your help -- appreciate it. If you've got a bit of spare time, it would be great to get some feedback on how the code for the warmup I've posted above specifically can be readjusted to solve this problem.

Comment: @marchon consider posting it to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (possibly there are other more appropriate sites, too). Your question is a bit fuzzy for SO, as there's no specific problem or question.

Comment: having  a look at this question. In your powerset pseudocode, what is "sets." I don't see where this argument is coming from but you seem to pass it in a recursive call at the end of that function. Would it be possible to clarify? @Rook

Comment: @marchon ahh, typo ;) fixed now. Incidentally, I have found a flaw in this code now... `std::set` cannot contain duplicate values. I have a workaround for this; I may add it later.

Comment: yup that's what I was running into as well, so I've been trying to see if something is possible using vectors. Would be great if you could add a little insight, I will add what I have as well...

Comment: @marchon the correct approach, I believe, is to set a set of vector indices... { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, build the powerset and then map them to voting block totals { 4, 2, 7, 4 } afterwards, to do the critical vote calculation. Using only vectors and totals makes the duplicate detection much harder.